# passing escape sequences from tmux to gnu screen

Tags: emacs, tmux, gnu-screen, gnome-terminal

For practical reasons, I am using tmux inside gnu screen (*).

Inside tmux, I have emacs, so far, everything is running well: fonts, characters, colours, etc.

Only one thing does not work with this configuration: changing the cursor shape, using the VTE escape sequences. If I use emacs inside tmux only, it works. If I use emacs in the terminal only, it works too.

I used the following code in the tmux.conf file:

```
set-option -ga terminal-overrides ",tmux-256color:Se=\\E[0 q"
set-option -ga terminal-overrides ",tmux-256color:Se=\\E[1 q"
set-option -ga terminal-overrides ",tmux-256color:Se=\\E[2 q"
set-option -ga terminal-overrides ",tmux-256color:Se=\\E[3 q"
set-option -ga terminal-overrides ",tmux-256color:Se=\\E[4 q"
set-option -ga terminal-overrides ",tmux-256color:Se=\\E[5 q"
set-option -ga terminal-overrides ",tmux-256color:Se=\\E[6 q"
```

And inside emacs:

```
;; Change the cursor shape according to the mode, in VTE based terminals
(add-hook 'overwrite-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
        (if overwrite-mode (send-string-to-terminal "\033[3 q")
        (send-string-to-terminal "\033[5 q"))
        )
      )

(add-hook 'read-only-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
        (if buffer-read-only (send-string-to-terminal "\033[2 q")
        (send-string-to-terminal "\033[5 q"))
        )
      )
```

So far, everything is working as expected. When I switch to overwrite mode, the cursor shape change into the terminal. However, if I run tmux inside screen, it does not work any more.

Can you tell me what I have to add to screen - or tmux configuration to make this working.

Thanks.

- I need to remotely connect on  multiple servers at once in one terminal, ant tmux inside screen is the most practical option. Especially since each of the remote servers runs tmux...